# Bootstrap modal to play videos and image slider with angular js

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show list of videos in Bootstrap modal. and when user clicks on any video from the list that video should play in modal only. similarly I want to show albums in modal and on click of specific album I want to show slideshow in the same modal, for this I am using angular js and Codeigniter with bootstrap. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a very descriptive question, but I recommend you check out [Angular UI's Bootstrap directives](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

I use their modal directive a lot and being able to specify a template and controller for a modal is priceless when it comes to working with things like you're describing.

**Update to address your comment:**

I have no idea where $scope.hall_videos is coming from, but you need to use the `resolve` property to return the correct videos. For instance, if `$scope.hall_videos` was an object where the key was the id and the value was an array of videos like so:

```
$scope.hall_videos = {
  '1': ['video1', 'video2'],
  ...
  '7': ['video14', 'video15']
};
```

You could populate with the correct videos like this:

```
$scope.open = function (size, id) {
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'video_gallery.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    size: size,
    resolve: {
      hall_videos: function () {
        var videos = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.hall_videos, function(video) {
          if (video.hall_info_id === id) {
            videos.push(video);
          }
        });
        return videos;
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Yes I did that using ui.bootstrap. example I have videos of marriage hall, when i click on hall number 7 then videos related to hall no. 7 must be displayed in modal. actually I am passing id too. but dont know how to fetch videos of id 7 in angularjs. sorry but now i did this much earlier I was not having any idea. Now help me to get videos of frd no. 7 in below example

Comment: $scope.open = function (size,id) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'video_gallery.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        hall_videos: function () {
          return $scope.hall_videos;
        }
      }
    });
  };

Comment: I updated my answer with a simple example of how you could use the id to grab the correct videos...I made some assumptions because I don't have the rest of your code to look at.

Comment: OK thanks sir u understood some flow of my app. Actually I have $scope.hall_videos = hall_videos; this hall_videos I am fetching like select * from service_videos; here service videos has fields like id, video_url, video_code, hall_info_id,video_name. Now I want hall_videos of hall_info_id 3. IN my code I am passing hall_info_id to modal controller. but I dont know how to fetch videos of hall_info_id 3. did you understood sir? I am fetching all the videos and storing in hall_videos. now based on id passed through ng-click i want videos tobe displayed. here is the code.

Comment: $scope.hall_videos=hall_videos;
  $scope.open = function (size,id) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'video_gallery.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        hall_videos: function () {
           alert("hii"+id);
          return $scope.hall_videos[id];
        }
      }
    });
  };

Comment: var hall_videos = 
[
{"id":"13","video_url":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?  v=qoq8B8ThgEM","video_code":"qoq8B8ThgEM","hall_info_id":"7","service_id":"1","video_name":"madhu","hall_name":"Sai mantap"},

{"id":"14","video_url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=MHzhK0QaBOg","video_code":"MHzhK0QaBOg","hall_info_id":"3","service_id":"2","video_name":"shubmangal","hall_name":"Tatiana"}
];
 in this way all the videos of hall_info_id are coming into my hall_videos.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I sleep once in a while. I updated my answer with a quick and easy forEach loop that will only return videos with the correct hall_info_id.

Comment: Thank you very very much sir...How can i contact you sir?

Comment: Sir now how can i send videos to my view i mean to my modal view which is in ng-template. videos is out of scope now. so in ng-repeat videos are now displaying. I checked with alert in ngforeach I can see videos are coming there but cant send those to my modal view. Please help me sir.